# Create a program that determines if the input data is a date or not

Tags: vb.net

please help, the output is still not the date even I put in my textbox like "12/2/2014". cannot determine it is date

[image: IMG1]

Comment: Try DateTime.TryParse Method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: still not working

Comment: @MichaelYsmaelFernandez Please [edit] your question to add the code as text, not as a picture of text.

Comment: Don't post pictures of code - post code as text and format it as code - and, if you are going to post a screenshot of something, don't capture the entire screen when only a small porting of it is relevant. Make an effort to help us help you, which would include not ignoring the prompt to take a tour of the site and learn how it works when you registered.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  My output format (dd/MM/yyyy) is for UK dates, but is just for demo.  Up to you how to handle the Date once you have it.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) handles Button1.Click

    Dim dateInput As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim ActualDate As DateTime
    If DateTime.TryParse(dateInput, ActualDate) Then
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The Date is {0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}", ActualDate), "SUCCESS")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Not a Valid Date", "ERROR")
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Date.Parse` will throw exception if `TextBox1.Text` doesn't contain a date. So, your `IsDate` is redundant. You need to use [DateTime.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse):

```
Dim dt As Date
If Date.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, dt) Then
    MessageBox.Show("It's a date")
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Not a date")
End If
```

### UPDATE

Please, note that the code above is for the case if you need a date itself. If you don't need it, `IsDate` is sufficient:

```
If IsDate(TextBox1.Text, dt) Then
    MessageBox.Show("It's a date")
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Not a date")
End If
```

Comment: I appreciate that Date and DateTime are synonymous in VB, but it might be better to make your code use DateTime so that a) it agrees with the recommendation to use DateTime.TryParse and b) it's perhaps less surprising when the Date is found to contain a time also - I think people who have "inherited VB6isms" see dates and times as different things, whereas the .net model of encouraging them to be seen as related concepts referencing "a moment" should be pushed more

Comment: Also, IsDate takes only one argument and I would perhaps at least disclaim (or not promote at all) use of things in the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace where possible, so if the VB coder ever makes the jump to another .net language, they aren't surprised by the lack of all those "legacy VB6 nomenclature" things